# Wifi connected but no data transfer

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking, router

I have a Desktop which runs on Windows XP and a laptop which runs in Ubuntu. Recently I have set up a wireless router in order to be able to access internet on my laptop through wifi. The laptop connects to the wifi at ease, but is unable to transfer any data. Only when I switch on my laptop for the first time, it is able to transfer some data only for around 2 mins, after which it shows Destination Host unreachable on pinging the router, and everything stops working, but the wifi still shows to be connected.

Please help!